# Getting a 404 on a valid URL when trying to submit async call from jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery method that looks like this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".txtTag", function (event) {
    var bomItemID = $(this).data('bomitemid');
    var tag = $(this).val();
    $.post("/BillOfMaterial/SetTag?BomItemID=" + bomItemID + "&Tag=" + tag, function (result) {
            // don't do anything
    });
});
```

In the browser's console, I get this error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:61560/BillOfMaterial/SetTag?BomItemID=3671&Tag=xz

But, when I click on that link, it works just fine.  I can even hit a breakpoint in the method SetTag() on the server.

Here's the server side method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SetTag(int BomItemID, string Tag)
{
    ... do stuff
    return Json("SUCCESS", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Using the decorator [HttpGet] will make that action only respond to 'GET' requests. You are using a 'POST'

Comment: Your HTTP verbs don't match. Either change `$.post` to `$.get` in the JS, or `[HttpGet]` to `[HttpPost]` in the Controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `[HttpPost]` request method, because you make a `post` request.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetTag(int BomItemID, string Tag)
{
    ... do stuff
    return Json("SUCCESS");
}
```

Another solution is to use `$.get` ajax call in order to keep `server-side` method declaration.

Comment: can't believe I missed that